# Why doesn't caching work without DI in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Say I have a Rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
    /* foobar instantiation/declaration goes here */

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String bar(@RequestParam(value = "baz") String baz) {
        return foobar.createResponse(baz);
    }
}
```

The `createResponse()` method is annotated with `@Cacheable`. 
When I just instantiate the foobar like `private Foobar foobar = new Foobar();`, caching doesn't work. 
But when using something like `@Autowired private Foobar foobar;`, caching works just fine.

I've been looking around a bit and as much as I understand caching in Spring uses proxy classes. So my question is can you not use caching without some sort of dependency injection? Is it because Spring has to inject the proxy class?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `private Foobar foobar = new Foobar();` you are creating a new object and not taking a object from spring container so there wont be any logging.

but when you use `@Autowired private Foobar foobar;` u take the object which is created by spring container spring injects the object to that reference.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is can you not use caching without some sort of
>   dependency injection

Dependency injection is not the cause of your problem. The problem is that you want to use Spring features but Spring features that empower/enrich objects of your application with specific or transverse features that you need (here cache ability) work as long as these objects are managed by Spring (commonly called Spring beans).
That is right for `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable` but also for transaction, injection, security, generated implementation, and so for...   features provided by Spring for our objects.

**You have to consider that Spring doesn't watch all objects present in the JVM. It would be complicated, very slow and it would be also undesirable because all object are not designed to be Spring beans.**

If you don't want to use to make this class a bean, don't use Spring for the caching feature. For example use EhCache alone. But as a result it will just make you to write more boiler plate code. If you use Spring, it would be very pity.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer this question you need to understand how does spring work.
I'll try tor provide a simple explanation, although again, a deep understanding of the responsibilities of spring as a framework will certainly help you here.

When you enable cache, spring effectively wraps your object (Foo in this case) into some sort of runtime-generated proxy that adds caching capabilities.

Now, spring can do this only with the objects that it manages.

So if you instantiate `Foo` by yourself (`Foo foo = new Foo()`) spring is effectively out of the game, spring even doesn't know that this object exists. So, of course, it won't create any kind of proxy here. Notice, that, even if Spring "knows" how to deal with objects of type `Foo` (read, there is a bean of type `Foo` in the application context), **it doesn't manage this concrete instance**

Now, if you go with auto-wiring (or with injecting the dependency in general), you say something completely different:

- Spring Manages the bean Foo (and if spring is not able to create instances of this bean, the application context won't start at all)
- Spring wraps the dependency with proxy that transparently adds caching capabilities and "bind" (inject) this dependency into your controller.

So, spring can do its job now - Caching works :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new object using new operator you will get that object instantiated by your own, means its lifecycle is not managed by Spring.

When you create a bean and autowires it, then its instantiation is managed by spring framework.

In case of caching, when you have @Cacheable annotated spring is returning a proxy instead of actual instantiated object. It's the responsibility of the proxy to cache the result, and put and evict cache based on the metadata (annotation) you provided.